# Why can't my entity framework database work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I was wondering can anybody see what I am doing wrong. I am tryng to create a database
    using entity framework and then seed but keep getting errors

Model - this is the model in which i have created a class a and b, the both have a fk
    i use dbcontext to try create the database

```
        namespace MvcAb.Models
{
    public class AaSeed : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<AaDb>
    {
        protected override void Seed(AaDb context)
        {
            context.Aas.Add(new Aa()
                {
                    AaName="Name",
                    AaDesc="Big Description",
                    Bbs = new List<Bb>()
                    {
                        new Bb()
                        {
                            BbName="This Name",
                            BbTitle="This title"
                        }//end new
                    }//end list
                });// end new Aa

                context.Aas.Add(new Aa()
                {
                    AaName="name two",
                    AaDesc="Second Desc"
                });

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public class AaDb : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Aa> Aas { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Bb> Bbs { get; set; }

        public AaDb() 
            : base("AaDb") 
        {

        }
    }


    public class Aa
    {
        public int AaId { get; set; }
        public string AaName { get; set; }
        public string AaDesc { get; set; }
        public List<Bb> Bbs { get; set; }
    }

    public class Bb
    {
        public int BbId { get; set; }
        public string BbName { get; set; }
        public string BbTitle { get; set; }
        public Aa Aa { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller - this is the controller page I create a new db to connect and then add to a list which will be shown in my view

```
    private AaDb Db = new AaDb();

        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(Db.Aas.ToList());
        }

        //
        // GET: /Home/Details/5

        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            return View(Db.Aas.Find(id));
        }
```

Index - this is my index where it should show the table and the data should be read in

```
    @model IEnumerable<MvcAb.Models.Aa>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Table of Data</h1>
        <p>
           @* @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")*@
        </p>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Id
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AaName)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AaDesc)
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AaId)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AaName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AaDesc)
                    </td>
                    <td>                     
                     @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.AaId })
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }

        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: You need to show the errors you are getting

Comment: Showing the errors would be very helpful. Also, you show your seed code, which implies that the problem is in the update-database, but you also show the controller and index code. Is your database getting created and populated with the data you expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*make sure to go to global.asax and put in this as I don't see your code for it*

```
Database.SetInitializer(new BlogSeed());
```

*and did you edit the connection string??*

```
add name="AaDb" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;I nitial Catalog=BlogDb;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I would seed it into vars

```
    var Bb = new List<Bb>()
        {
            new Bb() {},
        };
        //movie list var
        var Aa = new List<Aa>()
        {
            new Aa() {                  
            }
        };
        //save movie
        Bb.ForEach(a => context.Movie.Add(a));
        context.SaveChanges();
```